# how do I grab data from an API that returns CSV file

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am working with Pluralsight API and their API responds CSV files as results, which I would like to grab this data from response and print out.

this is the URL of the Pluralsight API:
https://app.pluralsight.com/plans/api/reports/docs

and this is the code I am trying to do:

```
  request
    .get('https://api.pluralsight.com/api-v0.9/users?planId=x&token=y')
    .on('response', function (response) {
        res.json(response);
    })
```

The response does not show any data except for the data as below:

```
  {
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "private",
    "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=Users.csv",
    "content-type": "text/csv",
    "date": "Fri, 27 May 2016 03:42:06 GMT",
    "ps-build": "2016.5.1849.0",
    "ps-node": "0Q5JR",
    "ps-responsetime": "00:00:00.1406230",
    "content-length": "11391",
    "connection": "Close"
  },
  "request": {
    "uri": {
      "protocol": "https:",
      "slashes": true,
      "auth": null,
      "host": "api.pluralsight.com",
      "port": 443,
      "hostname": "api.pluralsight.com",
      "hash": null,
      "search": "?planId=x&token=y",
      "query": "planId=x&token=y",
      "pathname": "/api-v0.9/users",
      "path": "/api-v0.9/users?planId=x&token=y",
      "href": "https://api.pluralsight.com/api-v0.9/users?planId=x&token=y",
    },
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {}
  }
}
```

Is there anyway that I get get the file from attachment and extract it?

Thanks

Comment: You're sending a json response but the data format is csv. Send the response in plain/text and see if you get the data, you can always parse it afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request body is accessible through `data` and `end` events.

```
var body = [];
request
    .get('https://api.pluralsight.com/api-v0.9/users?planId=x&token=y')
    .on('data', function (chunk) {
        body.push(chunk);
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        body = body.join('');
        // body now contains csv contents as a string
    });
```

Comment: is there also any way that I can convert this to a proper json format?

Comment: i mean how can i take record by record data?

Comment: @HisniFazlija You can use a CSV parser such as [node-csv](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv).